# How do enter all CloudFlare's captchas on one page to access a complex page?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, cloudflare

Sometimes I can access without a captcha from Tails a page, but not it's dependencies. For example, I can open a StackExchange question, but trying to go to https://cdn.sstatic.net/ triggers CloudFlare's captcha.

Before I enter the captcha, I see unstyled StackExchange page and scripts don't work, after I explicitly enter the captcha for other depencency domain the page starts working well.

How do I track and unlock the other CloudFlare-enabled domains for the given page? Is there, for example, a Tor Browser's addon that handles CloudFlare's rejection for dynamically loaded content explicitly and shows something like "You need to enter 3 captchas for the following domains".

**Workaround**:

1. Enable Developer Tools
2. go to Networking
3. try (re-)loading
4. observe 403 replies
5. open a new tab
6. go to the domain that retured 403
7. enter CloudFlare's captcha
8. goto 3.

Comment: Screenshot of what? Of the broken site due to inaccessible static content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such an option currently. You may want to make the Tor Browser people aware of your suggestion by opening a request on [Tor's bug tracker](https://trac.torproject.org).

Comment: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15450

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes entering a first captcha AND forcibly refreshing the whole page helps, for me it worked in FF and Chrome. It seems that a cookie is issued or a sessionID provided is marked as "non-malware". Does not work on any/all page(s), but sometimes helps(~40%)